# Want to add another row in tablix if my data is changed from the same field in RDLC

Tags: rdlc, rdl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98G1s.png)

in this tablix I have a field name Tax Type Code instead of hard coded GST/HSTAmountLbl. That field(TaxTypeCode) is getting the name of tax type.

Now I'm expecting to do something on this tablix that if the value of my field i.e; TaxTypeCode changes then it add the field on different row and show the related amount on this whole row.

Please help me I'm so confused. :-(